# Apache hanging on Windows Server 2012

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2012

I configured Apache/PHP on a Windows 2012 server and everything runs smoothly for a few hours then Apache hangs and my website is not responsive.

I did find this entry in my Apache error log:
[mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 3884:tid 1504] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available. : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.

After doing some research I found some posts saying that I should use:
Acceptfilter https none

However, it looks like there is a bug in Apache 2.4.2 when using this directive with https (my entire website runs on https). See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52476 for more information about the bug)

So I cannot use Acceptfilter https none.

I have a couple of questions that I hope somebody can help me answer:
1. Why do I need to disable filters to fix my problem? (I still don't know if this will actually fix it).
2. My website hasn't been tested with Apache 2.4.4 and I do not what the upgrade to introduce any errors. Is there a way I can fix my problem without upgrading to Apache 2.4.4? If not, then if anybody knows of any common errors that can be introduced when upgrading to Apache 2.4.4, please share.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can always load up a VM to see what results you get with your webiste witht latest version of apache.  Keeping your system up-to-date is important from a security standpoint anyway.  Then again, I have no idea how complex your web environment is either.  But being as though you aren't using IIS, seems like replicating your environment shouldn't be horrible anyway. http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html